# How do I find where Sesame stores repositories?

Tags: tomcat, owl, sesame

I'm using booth Sesame .wars in Tomcat 7 on OS X 10.8, but now it doesn't work any more. I set up a new Tomcat with two new Sesame .war but now it uses the old repository. Where are these stored? (Couldn't add a new Repo or delete the old one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sesame Server by default stores its configuration data and database files in  `%APPDATA%\Aduna` on Windows, `$HOME/.aduna` on Linux, and `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Aduna` on Mac OS X. If you want a completely new install, simply delete this directory. [See the Sesame manual](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#chapter-datadir-config) for more info.

**Update** you can check where your Sesame server installation stores its data by going to

```
http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame/home/overview.view
```

in your browser, and clicking "System" in the navigation menu on the left hand side. It shows you various configuration settings, including the data directory.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but I couldn't found .aduna in my home folder (hidden files are shown). When I set the java variable the folder would be created, but the repo is still available

Answer (score 2):

Sesame home is as follows:

```
$HOME/.aduna/openrdf-sesame (linux/unix)
"%APPDATA%\Aduna\OpenRDF Sesame" (Windows)
"$HOME/Library/Application Support/Aduna/OpenRDF Sesame" (Mac OS X)
```

From the Owlim documentation.