# Where does Sesame 2.7 store Native repositories on disk?

Tags: storage, sesame

I want to have the size of a sesame repository on my disk. So I wonder where does Sesame 2.7 store all repositories that its handle ?

Any idea about it is welcome !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find where Sesame stores repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905605/how-do-i-find-where-sesame-stores-repositories)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the Sesame Documentation says](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#chapter-datadir-config) :

> All OpenRDF applications (Sesame Server, Workbench, and Console) store
>   configuration files and repository data in a single directory (with
>   subdirectories). On Windows machines, this directory is
>   %APPDATA%\Aduna\ by default, where %APPDATA% is the application data
>   directory of the user that runs the application. For example, in case
>   the application runs under the 'LocalService' user account on Windows
>   XP, the directory is C:\Documents and
>   Settings\LocalService\Application Data\Aduna. On Linux/UNIX, the
>   default location is $HOME/.aduna/, for example /home/tomcat/.aduna/

You will find the Native repository data under this directory, in the subdirectory openrdf-sesame/repositories/{name_of_the_repository}