# Where is GraphDB data directory?

Tags: graphdb

I am having problem locating the data directory for [GraphDB](http://ontotext.com/products/graphdb/) version 6.6, I am pretty sure it is in the documentation [Documentation](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/6.6/standard/toc.html), but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is from a previous version of [GraphDB documentation](https://confluence.ontotext.com/display/OWLIM55/OWLIM-SE+Installation#OWLIM-SEInstallation-Stepbystep(vanilla)):

```
Locate the data directory here:
  $HOME/.aduna/openrdf-sesame-console* (linux/unix)
  "%APPDATA%\Aduna\OpenRDF Sesame console" (Windows)
  "$HOME/Library/Application Support/Aduna/OpenRDF Sesame console" (Mac OS X)
```

Now, knowing the answer, I can track this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905605/how-do-i-find-where-sesame-stores-repositories#12906755) on SO that I didn't see before.