# error "Multiple ID-statements for repository ID" on repository drop/create

Tags: graphdb

On [GraphDB](http://ontotext.com/products/graphdb/), [version 6.6](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/6.6/standard/toc.html) I get this error when trying to drop a repository from the command line :

```
Commands end with '.' at the end of a line
Type 'help.' for help
> show r.
show r
+----------
|SYSTEM ("System configuration repository")
|knora-test ("Knora test repository")
+----------
> drop knora-test.
drop knora-test
Unable to drop repository 'knora-test': Multiple ID-statements for repository ID knora-test
>
```

This repository doesn't show up in the [web workbench](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/6.6/standard/workbench-user-guide.html).

Looking further the the exception behind the error is:

```
org.openrdf.repository.config.RepositoryConfigException: Multiple ID-statements for repository ID knora-test
    at org.openrdf.repository.config.RepositoryConfigUtil.getIDStatement(RepositoryConfigUtil.java:269)
    at org.openrdf.repository.config.RepositoryConfigUtil.hasRepositoryConfig(RepositoryConfigUtil.java:91)
    at org.openrdf.repository.manager.RemoteRepositoryManager.removeRepository(RemoteRepositoryManager.java:269)
    at org.openrdf.console.Drop.dropRepository(Drop.java:99)
    at org.openrdf.console.Drop.execute(Drop.java:59)
    at org.openrdf.console.Console.executeCommand(Console.java:290)
    at org.openrdf.console.Console.start(Console.java:271)
    at org.openrdf.console.Console.main(Console.java:129)
```

Answer (score 2):

a fix to this is to delete the repository by hand, navigate to the [data directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905605/how-do-i-find-where-sesame-stores-repositories#12906755), spot your faulty repository and delete it.

Comment: Dear Loic, I ran into the same problem, would you mind explaining more in detail how to fix it?

Comment: Hello Jan, in my case this happened after some intensive data import, replacing previous data set, so there was a `drop` first and a safe back-up.

Comment: So I only deleted the files in the file system, loosing all data if you don't have a back-up.

If you are using the a docker instance like on your https://github.com/nie-ine/Quick-Installation-Guide---Knora-Salsah-Sipi-GraphDB/blob/master/docker-compose.yml compose file, this means you can simply delete the container.

Comment: Otherwise, when graphdb starts, it prints its data directory in the first lines of it log:

    [INFO ] 2018-04-16 08:19:15,105 [localhost-startStop-1 | c.o.g.Config] GraphDB Data directory: /Users/ljaouen/Soft/install/graphdb/graphdb-se-8.0.3/data

then I just delete this directory.

Sorry for the very bad formatting. Let me know if it is not clear.